# Proof of an Integral Function

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

How can I begin writing down the proof of this equation?

$
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{\sqrt{2au-u^2}}{u^2} du = \mathrm{i}\ln\left(\left|a\sqrt{\left(2a-u\right)u}+\mathrm{i}\left|a\right|\left(u-a\right)\right|\right)-\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}-\dfrac{\sqrt{-u\cdot\left(u-2a\right)}}{u}
\end{align*}
$

Here are the steps I have done, please point out if I have made a problem over here,

Integrate by parts:

$\int f g^{\prime}=f g-\int f^{\prime} g$
$\mathrm{f}=\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}, \quad \mathrm{~g}^{\prime}=\frac{1}{u^2}$

$f^{\prime}=\frac{2 a-2 u}{2 \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}, g=-\frac{1}{u}:$
$=-\frac{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}{u}-\int-\frac{2 a-2 u}{2 u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u$

Now solve:
$$
\int-\frac{2 a-2 u}{2 u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Rewrite:
$$
=\int \frac{u-a}{u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Perform polynomial long division on the factor $\frac{u-a}{u}$ :
$$
=\int\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}-\frac{a}{u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}\right) \mathrm{d} u
$$
Apply linearity:
$$
=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u-a \int \frac{1}{u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Now solve:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Complete the square:
$$
=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-(u-a)^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Substitute $v=\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a} \longrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{~d} u}=\frac{\mathrm{i}}{a}$ (steps) $\longrightarrow \mathrm{d} u=-\mathrm{i} a \mathrm{~d} v$ :
$$
=\int-\frac{\mathrm{i} a}{\sqrt{a^2 v^2+a^2}} \mathrm{~d} v
$$
Simplify:
$$
=-\mathrm{i} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+1}} \mathrm{~d} v
$$
Now solving:
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+1}} \mathrm{~d} v
$$
This is a standard integral:
$$
=\ln \left(\sqrt{v^2+1}+v\right)
$$
Plug in solved integrals:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&-\mathrm{i} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2+1}} \mathrm{~d} v \\
=&-\mathrm{i} \ln \left(\sqrt{v^2+1}+v\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Undo substitution $v=\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a}$ :
$$
=-\mathrm{i} \ln \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{(u-a)^2}{a^2}}+\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a}\right)
$$
What should I do next?
Edit: I found the answer after drinking a cup of milk and wasting sketch papers as follows, I am blocked from making answer, so I am writing it here.
I solved it myself afterwards,and reached the final solution myself. The answer continues from where I left the solution in question.
Now solve:
$$
\int \frac{1}{u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Complete the square:
$$
=\int \frac{1}{u \sqrt{a^2-(u-a)^2}} \mathrm{~d} u
$$
Substitute $v=u-a \longrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} v}{\mathrm{~d} u}=1$ (steps) $\longrightarrow \mathrm{d} u=\mathrm{d} v$, use:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{1}{u}=\frac{1}{v+a} \\
=\int \frac{1}{(v+a) \sqrt{a^2-v^2}} \mathrm{~d} v
\end{gathered}
$$
Perform hyperbolic substitution:
Substitute $v=a \tanh (w) \longrightarrow w=\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{v}{a}\right), \mathrm{d} v=a \operatorname{sech}^2(w) \mathrm{d} w$ (steps):
$$
=\int \frac{a \operatorname{sech}^2(w)}{(a \tanh (w)+a) \sqrt{a^2-a^2 \tanh ^2(w)}} \mathrm{d} w
$$
Simplify using $a^2-a^2 \tanh ^2(w)=a^2 \operatorname{sech}^2(w)$ :
$$
=\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{\operatorname{sech}(w)}{\tanh (w)+1} \mathrm{~d} w
$$
Now solving:
$$
\int \frac{\operatorname{sech}(w)}{\tanh (w)+1} d w
$$
Write trigonometric/hyperbolic functions using exponentials:
$$
=\int \mathrm{e}^{-w} \mathrm{~d} w
$$
Substitute $x=-w \longrightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{~d} w}=-1$ (steps) $\longrightarrow \mathrm{d} w=-\mathrm{d} x$ :
$$
=-\int \mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{~d} x
$$
Now solving:
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{~d} x
$$
Apply exponential rule:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \mathrm{a}^x \mathrm{~d} x=& \frac{\mathrm{a}^x}{\ln (\mathrm{a})} \text { with } \mathbf{a}=\mathrm{e}: \\
&=\mathrm{e}^x
\end{aligned}
$$
Plug in solved integrals:
$$
\begin{gathered}
-\int \mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{~d} x \\
=-\mathrm{e}^x
\end{gathered}
$$
Undo substitution $x=-w$ :
$$
=-\mathrm{e}^{-w}
$$
Plug in solved integrals:
$$
\begin{gathered}
\frac{1}{a} \int \frac{\operatorname{sech}(w)}{\tanh (w)+1} \mathrm{~d} w \\
=-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-w}}{a}
\end{gathered}
$$
Undo substitution $w=\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{v}{a}\right)$ :
$\quad=-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{v}{a}\right)}}{a}$ Undo substitution $v=u-a:$ $=-\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}}{a}$
Plug in solved integrals:
$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u-a \int \frac{1}{u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u$
$=\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}-\mathrm{i} \ln \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{(u-a)^2}{a^2}}+\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a}\right)$
$-\frac{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}{u}-\int-\frac{2 a-2 u}{2 u \sqrt{2 a u-u^2}} \mathrm{~d} u$
$=\mathrm{i} \ln \left(\sqrt{1-\frac{(u-a)^2}{a^2}}+\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a}\right)-\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}{u}$

The problem is solved almost. Apply the absolute value function to arguments of logarithm functions in order to extend the antiderivative's domain:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}{u^2} \mathrm{~d} u \\
&=\mathrm{i} \ln \left(\left|\sqrt{1-\frac{(u-a)^2}{a^2}}+\frac{\mathrm{i} \cdot(u-a)}{a}\right|\right)-\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{2 a u-u^2}}{u}}+C \\
&\text { Rewrite/simplify: } \\
&=\mathrm{i} \ln (|a \sqrt{(2 a-u) u}+\mathrm{i}| a|(u-a)|)-\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}-\frac{\sqrt{-u \cdot(u-2 a)}}{u}+C
\end{aligned}
$$
Any error follow-up or comment is appreciated, plus thanks if you find an alternative.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @ChrisSanders merci, mais je ne pense pas que parce que nous ne connaissons pas la constante C?

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks, let me edit the question with everything I know

Comment: @AitzazImtiaz the constant $C$ is going to be there anyway. The point is that if the derivative of the stuff on the right is $\frac{\sqrt{2au-u^2}}{u^2}$, then you've already proven the equation. And derivatives are straightforward to compute using product rule, chain rule etc.

Comment: @ChrisSanders merci, je l’ai eu!

Comment: @AnotherUser is this edit fine?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: Note that $$\int\frac{\sqrt{2au-u^2}}{u^2} du = -2\sqrt{\frac{2a}u-1}+\sin^{-1}\left(1-\frac ua\right)+C
$$

Comment: then the right side of that equation is equal to  $\mathrm{i}\ln\left(\left|a\sqrt{\left(2a-u\right)u}+\mathrm{i}\left|a\right|\left(u-a\right)\right|\right)-\mathrm{e}^{-\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{u-a}{a}\right)}-\dfrac{\sqrt{-u\cdot\left(u-2a\right)}}{u}$

Comment: I think I forgot to add the C constant above.

Comment: Also, this equation serves as a gateway relation between imaginary and real numbers.